# State of charge estimation algorithms applicability to primary cells

Tags: batteries

Most references that I have seen refer to SoC estimation in a frame of electric vehicles.

My question is do these methods apply to primary cells? If so, do all these methods, and coulomb counting specifically, apply to primary cells?

Comment: Is this a school question?  What are your thoughts?

Comment: @KH, it is not a school question. I am a mechanical engineer with a background in signal processing. I am considering implementing the coulomb counting on a primary cell and would like to know if it is feasible...
Also, I would like to understand if the rest of the methods are restricted to the secondary cells or the are applicable to the primary cell too.

Comment: If you can detect when cells are swapped (to reset the counter), and you know that only new cells are ever inserted, and you know that the capacity of new cells is consistent, I don't see why not. But these three assumptions are perhaps not trivial.

Comment: Ok.  I'll take your word then.  Main problem I see is that you find out the ratio between coulombs in, actual stored charge and coulombs out partly by repeated charging cycles.  With a primary cell it can be hard to say how much is in a battery to start with without depleting one.  You can kind of guess at capacity, but it would vary a bit with manufacture and it depletes over time.  Whether it was worth the effort would depend on how valuable a forecast of remaining power is.

Comment: @KH, But assuming that I know the initial capacity based on the datasheet, I can estimate the remaining SoC, right? Also, do the other methods, including the Kalam filter are applicable too?